# Make Mysql count even if value is equal to zero

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count number of items by categories and i want to show 0 on categories with no items
My actual code doen't consider categories with 0 value

```
SELECT categories.categories_id, categories_name, categories_active, categories_status, 
COUNT(IFNULL( product.product_id,0)) as count 
FROM categories 
LEFT JOIN product ON product.categories_id = categories.categories_id
WHERE categories_status = 1 AND product.active = 1
GROUP BY categories.categories_id
```

suppose we have two tables categories and products

```
cat_id  cat_name
1   cat A
2   cat B
3   cat C

product_id  product_name    cat_id
1               prod A      1
2               prod B      2
3               prod C      1
4               prod X      2
```

i expect to get

```
cat_id  cat_name    count products
1   cat A           2
2   cat B           2
3   cat C           0
```

Comment: Not very clear what you want to achieve here! Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use

```
AND product.active = 1
```

and you filter out null values (categories without products) because of this condition. Try like this:

```
AND (product.active = 1 OR product.active IS NULL)
```

final query:

```
SELECT categories.categories_id, categories_name, categories_active, categories_status, 
COUNT(product.product_id) AS count 
FROM categories 
LEFT JOIN product ON product.categories_id = categories.categories_id
WHERE categories_status = 1 AND (product.active = 1 OR product.active IS NULL)
GROUP BY categories.categories_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `COUNT(*)`. It counts every row generated by your from/ join / where clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of left join use right join and change the COUNT(IFNULL( product.product_id,0)) to COUNT(product.product_id).Try this once.

```
SELECT categories.categories_id, categories_name, categories_active, categories_status, 
    COUNT(product.product_id) as count 
    FROM categories 
    RIGHT JOIN product ON product.categories_id = categories.categories_id
    WHERE categories_status = 1 AND product.active = 1
    GROUP BY categories.categories_id
```

By right join you will get count 0 data also